# Second line of data file is not read correctly

Tags: c++

Why is my program is reading the wrong value for the second line from the text file?
while reading the last character of the first line, it returns a string "1\n-1".

Data file:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
1 -1 -1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1
```

Code:

```
vector<vector<int>> input_vector, pinput_vector;
vector<int> patterns_vector;

for(auto i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    patterns_vector.push_back(1);
    for(auto j = 1; j < 15; j++)
    {
        getline(training, s,' ');
        cout << s;
        patterns_vector.push_back(stoi(s));
    }
        input_vector.push_back(patterns_vector);
        patterns_vector.clear();
}
for(auto i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for(auto j = 1; j < 15; j++)
    {
        cout << input_vector.at(i).at(j);
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Well, what did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: At that point, i get a string “1\n-1”

Comment: `std::getline()` isn't a good tool to split up input with a different delimiter than `'\n'` just use whole lines and split them up reading from a `std::istringstream`.

Comment: oh yes. thanks, it worked.

Comment: *Seems like people are more interested in correcting the question format* -- Thousands of professionals are looking at the question.  This isn't a personal chat site, thus the reason why others are putting the question in a format that is professional and presentable to the programming public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you [read whole lines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) into a string, put that string into an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and with the help of [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) construct the inner vector directly.

Perhaps something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> input_vector;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(training, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    input_vector.emplace_back(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss),
                              std::istream_iterator<int>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Then I tried operator like training >> s instead of get line function and it worked too.